# how to handle navigation of react application using 'react speech recognition Api'

Tags: reactjs, web, speech

I am creating a react app but I want to handle navigation of my app
using voice I have added very much like its listning to me but still
not navigation and one one thing om using here `useEffect` to listen
me itself but its annoying to keep listning without stopping, here is
my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Product from "./pages/Product";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import ProductList from "./pages/ProductList";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Cart from "./pages/Cart";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min";
import Success from "./pages/Success";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import FormComponent from "./customization/CustomizeForm";
import FilteredProducts from "./pages/FilteredProducts";
import SpeechRecognition, { useSpeechRecognition } from 'react-speech-recognition'

const App = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);
  const commands = [
    {
      command: "go home",
      callback: () => {
        history.push("/");
      },
    },
    {
      command: "go to products",
      callback: () => {
        history.push("/products");
      },
    },
    {
      command: "go to cart",
      callback: () => {
        history.push("/cart");
      },
    },
    // Add more voice commands and corresponding callbacks for navigation
  ];
  const { transcript, browserSupportsSpeechRecognition } = useSpeechRecognition({ commands })
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   SpeechRecognition.startListening({ language: 'en-IN' });

  // });
  if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
    return null
  }
  console.log("transcript", transcript)
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/products/:category">
          <ProductList />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/product/:id">
          <Product />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/cart">
          <Cart />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/success">
          <Success />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          {user ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Login />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/register">
          {user ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Register />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/customize">
          <FormComponent />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/filteredProducts">
          <FilteredProducts />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Please state me if something is wrong here

Comment: Can you make a minimum example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new